# Can I use non-alphanumeric element names in HAML?

Tags: xml, haml, cjk

I need to generate a legacy XML that has japanese element names.

```
!!! XML
%こんにちわ
  %素晴らしき
  %世界
```

However, invalid tag error will raise when renders it .

```
pry(main)> Haml::Engine.new("!!! XML\n%こんにちわ\n    %素晴らしき\n     %世界").render
Haml::SyntaxError: Invalid tag: "%こんにちわ".
from (haml):2
```

How can I render it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that Haml is not going to be the right tool for you to create your legacy XML files.  Although it is true that [XML element and attribute names can use non-ASCII characters](http://www.opentag.com/xfaq_charrep.htm#char_nonasciitag), when I run your code in my IRB, I get the same error as you:

```
irb> Haml::Engine.new("!!! XML\n%こんにちわ\n    %素晴らしき\n     %世界").render
Haml::SyntaxError: Invalid tag: "%こんにちわ".
from (haml):2
from /Users/paul/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/haml-4.0.7/lib/haml/parser.rb:520:in `parse_tag'
```

So, the error seems to be in [`Haml::Parser#parse_tag`](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/lib/haml/parser.rb#L568), where you can see the potential issue in the guard clause in the first two lines of the method:

```
match = text.scan(/%([-:\w]+)([-:\w.#]*)(.+)?/)[0]
raise SyntaxError.new(Error.message(:invalid_tag, text)) unless match
```

Let's see what the value of `match` is for different tags:

```
irb> "%html".scan(/%([-:\w]+)([-:\w.#]*)(.+)?/)[0]
=> ["html", "", nil]
irb> "%こんにちわ".scan(/%([-:\w]+)([-:\w.#]*)(.+)?/)[0]
=> nil
```

So, that seems to be the issue: although the Japanese tags may be legal for XML itself, you won't get them past Haml's parser (unless you perhaps attempt to monkey patch it yourself).

Comment: Thanks, Paul. It seems like a bad choice for changing the tag matcher can be use the Japanese with monky patche. I will use erb instead haml.